# Get only decimal sign from react-intl <FormattedNumber>

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I just need to get correct decimal sign for current locale. (. or ,)
Is it possible to get it from react-intl ?
Or is there some other way in react-intl to get to correct decimal sign.

Comment: `formatNumber(.1).replace(/\d/g, '')` but there should be a better way :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the decimal and thousands separator in ECMAscript Internationalization API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722876/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-decimal-and-thousands-separator-in-ecmascript-internat)